# How can I display the correct result of my sql query in php?

Tags: php, sql, database, select, pdo

My php code:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "123asd";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=bd_actividades", $username, $password);
    echo "Connected successfully";
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT pro_nombre FROM act_proyecto");
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo $result;
}catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
?>
```

And show this:

[image]

Why does it show 1?

I need this (pro_nombre) :

[image]

How can I fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fetch the result, you just set the fetch MODE.

Change this:

```
$result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo $result;
```

To this:

```
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
foreach ($result as $row) {
    echo $row['pro_nombre'];
}
```

Comment: can you help me with this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30494858/how-can-i-mix-this-codes-to-show-the-correct-results-in-relation-my-sql-query-wi

Answer (score 1):

[`setFetchMode`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.setfetchmode.php) returns a boolean.  That is why it is printing `1` (the `true` is cast as `1` when you echo it).

Instead you need to do `$result = $stmt->fetchAll();` (http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) or iterate using `fetch`.

Comment: I usually just do `$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` on my database object so that I don't have to worry about it later on.

Comment: @Mike I prefer assoc fetch mode as well

Comment: If I put $result = $stmt->fetchAll();  and now print "array"(only the word "array") the same if only I put fetch. Thanks for answer.

Comment: It's printing "Array" because `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` means it will fetch an associative array.

Comment: @JeanAndrésBergeretFuhrhop you can use `print_r` or `var_dump` instead of `echo` to see the contents of the array, but most likely you want to iterate over this and print out some HTML or something like that, or just `echo` individual columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = $sth->fetchAll();
print_r($result);
```

if you need a table

```
?>
<table border="1" style="width:100%">
<?php foreach($result as $row){ ?>
    <tr>
        <td> <?php echo $row['pro_nombre'] ?></td>
    </tr> 
<?php }?>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't think the OP was asking how to format it as a table. I think he was wondering why it was printing `1` instead of displaying the results of the query.